# Как подключить файлы в цикле?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть такой каталог, в файлах `models.txt` находится `json`

```
cars
-- lada
  -- models.txt
-- kia
  -- models.txt
.........
```

Как в цикле подключить все файлы `models.txt` ?

На выводе хочу получить данные в таком виде:

```
$cars = [
  'lada' => ... здесь значение файла models.txt но в массиве (json_encode)
  'kia' => ... здесь значение файла models.txt но в массиве (json_encode)
  ... и тд
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде нашел решение, но не понятно как проверить на корректность json чтобы в случае чего не выдавало ошибку

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__);

$cars = [];
$skip = ['.', '..'];
$files = scandir(ROOT .'/cars');
foreach($files as $file){
    if(!in_array($file, $skip)){
        if(is_file(ROOT .'/cars/'. $file .'/models.txt')){
            $model = file_get_contents(ROOT .'/cars/'. $file .'/models.txt');
            if($model) $cars[$file] = json_decode($model);
        }
    }
}
```